# Unable to prevent formatting in PHP string literals

Tags: regex, string, aptana, literals, formatter

I have a line of code like this in my php:

```
$val = preg_replace('/<\/?div.*?>/', '', str_replace("<br />", " - ", $item->getItemName()));
```

When I run the Aptana PHP formatter on it I get:

```
$val = preg_replace('/<\/?div.*
?>/
', '', str_replace("
<br />
", " - ", $item->getItemName()));
```

I created a custom formatter and enabled on/off tags and setup my code like so:

```
//@formatter:off
$val = preg_replace('/<\/?div.*?>/', '', str_replace("<br />", " - ", $item->getItemName()));
//@formatter:on
```

But it still formats it. Obviously it's the HTML formatter getting triggered, so I even tried turning that off just in the off chance it was the problem:

```
//<!--@formatter:off-->
$val = preg_replace('/<\/?div.*?>/', '', str_replace("<br />", " - ", $item->getItemName()));
//<!--@formatter:on-->
```

Still no luck. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate this one, but with no real success.

When I have this code, the formatter works just fine:

```
<?php
$val = preg_replace('/<\/?div.*?>/', '', str_replace("<br />", " - ", $item -> getItemName()));
?>
```

Removing the opening `<?php` tag, and the closing `?>`, will actually invoke the HTML formatter on the code, as it will be treated as HTML in a PHP file.

If you post the complete file here, it will be easier to see where is the mistake, or if there is an issue with the formatter somewhere.

Hope that helps.